# Does Cygwin's rsync support Unicode filenames?

Tags: windows, unicode, rsync

It does not seem to but I may be missing something. Is the default installation of Cygwin RSYNC on Windows 7 support Unicode filenames? I'm trying to sync files from a Mac to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that Cygwin itself supports them, but the Windows console window that it runs in does not. You can change the console to use the UTF-8 code page:

```
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/chcp.com 65001
```

Comment: Just a note for anyone who runs across this posting, changing the code page of the console does NOT allow rsync to support file names with unicode characters in them. On a side note it baffles me that this is still a problem in 2013. It's been an issue since at least the middle of the last decade.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer helped in my case, but only after I set UTF-8 encoding for Cygwin as well:

```
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/chcp.com 65001
export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
```